# Couldn't target the organization using CF

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson

i used `cf target` to get the current target information
but i get this error

'cf' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

i installed the CLI[image]

Comment: i need to Target the Organization and Space in which i created my Node.js Cloud Foundry App

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you installed the IBM Cloud CLI, all commands start by calling the CLI by either **ibmcloud** or **bx**. You can use `ibmcloud cf` followed by Cloud Foundry commands.

Ue `ibmcloud target --cf` to interactively pick the org and space. If that does not give the right choices or an error: Are you connected to the correct region? Use `ibmcloud target -r the-region` to set the region and replace **the-region** with, e.g., **us-south**.

Comment: i did it thanks! , but when i tried to push the files everything was ok, until   Waiting for app to start...
TIP: use 'cf.exe logs Tutankhamun-Chatbot --recent' for more information
FAILED

Comment: My answer addresses your question. Please upvote and mark as answered. Then ask your next question. (Tip: include how you pushed and what)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.
how i pushed and what?
files like this i just modified but i get an error
https://github.com/lukemccomb/watson-assistant-chatbot-ui#step_8iii

Comment: add that to the new question :) Mark this one as answered (click on the check mark)

Comment: please can you see this problem 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57774652/node-js-execute-function-before-complete-multiple-lines-of-code?noredirect=1#comment101984810_57774652

look at my comments please.